# Spring Security giving 405 but still logging in

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm developing a blog-like website with Spring Boot. I've previously had a built in account for logging in to the site, and I've developed registration as well. I've made confirmation emails as well. They were working, and I've tried logging in, but I've got constantly redirected to the login page whenever I pressed the login button. I'm not sure where I went wrong, and I've made so many changes, it'd take quite a lot to backtrack every step. I somehow managed to half-fix the issue, now I get a 405 error, but if I go to the home page, I find myself logged in.

I've tried looking through various 405 related questions, but almost all of it uses csrf, which I turned off at the beginning (I know it's not a good practice, but I had to). I've tried rearranging the configure method, use different loginProcessingUrl, adding/removing defaultSuccessUrl, failureForwardUrl, successForwardUrl, etc.. I'm not sure what part of my code you'd need, as even nor I'm sure where everything went haywire.

So the following happens: if I define `loginProcessingUrl`, I get logged in, but redirected on a 405 site. If I don't define `loginProcessingUrl` I will get redirected to the login page, and from the network tab I'll get 302, but no error at all.

I'm using org.springframework.boot version 2.7.0

Here is my SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BlogSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/v2/**")
                .antMatchers("/webjars/**")
                .antMatchers("/image/**")
                .antMatchers("/static-image/**")
                .antMatchers("/test/**");
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/user/login")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate")
                    //.defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
                    //.failureForwardUrl("/")
                    //.successForwardUrl("/")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/documentation/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/admin/**", "/files/upload-image").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/user/registration", "/user/registration_success", "/user/confirm").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/", "/blog/**", "/category/**", "/about", "/contact-us", "/privacy-policy", "/error").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager customAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return authenticationManager();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
}
```

Here's MyUserDetailsService

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
@Transactional
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyUserDetailsService.class);
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email).orElse(userRepository.findByUsername(email).orElse(null));
        if(user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user found with credentials: " + email);
        }
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.isActive() && ! user.isBanned(), true, true, true, getAuthorities(user.getRoles()));
    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Collection<Role> roles) {
        return getGrantedAuthorities(getPrivileges(roles));
    }

    private List<String> getPrivileges(Collection<Role> roles) {
        List<String> privileges = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Privilege> collection = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Role role : roles) {
            privileges.add(role.getName());
            collection.addAll(role.getPrivileges());
        }
        for(Privilege item : collection) {
            privileges.add(item.getName());
        }
        return privileges;
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(List<String> privileges) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String privilege: privileges) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(privilege));
        }
        return authorities;
    }
}
```

This is the controller for the login:

```
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    private final SecurityService securityService;

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login(Model model, String error, String logout) {
        if(securityService.isAuthenticated()) {
            return "redirect:/";
        }

        return "user/login";
    }
    
    /*Omitted unrelated functions*/

}
```

Here's the form I'm using to log in:

```
            <form id="loginForm" method="POST" action="/authenticate">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <input id="username" autofocus="true" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username"
                               type="text"/>
                        <label for="username">Username</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <input id="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password"/>
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                    </div>

                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Login</button>
                    <h4 class="text-center"><a href="/user/registration">Registration</a></h4>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Tell me if you need something else, I'd be glad to provide you with more info if needed

---

Update 1) I've previously used the `/login` endpoint for the login page. I've rolled back only the SecurityConfig, and the controller, and set the form's action to POST to `/login`. I still don't have any `@PostMapping("/login")`, so it uses the built in. I'm not sure why it's working this way, but not with `/user/login`. This is the current version of the SecurityConfig:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/documentation/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/admin/**", "/files/upload-image").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/user/registration", "/user/registration_success", "/user/confirm").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/", "/blog/**", "/category/**", "/about", "/contact-us", "/privacy-policy", "/error").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                    .logout()
                    .permitAll();

    }
```

Comment: enable DEBUG or TRACE logs and update your question with them.